# Carousel is not displayed

Tags: react-tsx

The Carousel is not displayed in React. I am trying to display news from the server to the page through the carousel. The data is extracted from the server, checked. The carousel does not appear on the page and does not throw errors. Please help here is the code.

News.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import './News.css';

interface INews{
    name: string;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;
    onClick: () => void;
}

function News({name, description, imageUrl, onClick} : INews) {
    return (
        <div className='news'>
            <h1>{name}</h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
            <img src={imageUrl} alt={"img news"} />
            <button onClick={onClick} className='imgBut' title="Enter"/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default News;
```

MyCarosel.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import { Carousel } from "react-responsive-carousel";
import News from "../News/News";
import { New } from "../../Entity/News";

const items: New[] = [];

const MyCarousel = ({ items }: { items: New[] }) => {
    const enterClick = () => {
        // Handle the button click event here
        console.log('Button clicked!');
    };

    return (
      <Carousel className="myCar">
        {items.map((item) => (
            <News
                name = {item.name}
                description= {item.description}
                imageUrl= {item.imageUrl}
                onClick= {enterClick}
            />
        ))}
      </Carousel>
    );
  };
  
  export default MyCarousel;
```

Home.tsx

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import Header from '../Headers/Header';
import Fotter from '../Fotter/Fotter';
import { getNews } from '../../ApiService/ApiService';
import MyCarousel from '../MyCarosel/MyCarosel';
import { New } from '../../Entity/News';

function Home() {
    let news: New[] = [];

    //get news
    useEffect(() => {
        // Викликаємо функцію при завантаженні сторінки
        getNews()
          .then(data => {
            // Отримані дані доступні тут
            news = data;
          })
          .catch(error => {
            // Обробка помилки
            console.error(error);
          });
      }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <Header/>
            <div>
                <MyCarousel items={news}/>
            </div>
            <Fotter/>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

New.tsx

```
export class New{
    id: Int32Array;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    imageUrl: string;

    constructor(id: Int32Array, name: string, description: string, imageUrl: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
      }
};
```

I tried to check whether the data is coming from the server. Everything is coming good.